# magento2 mysql update table query

Tags: mysql

If someone can help with this MySQL query that would be great

I want to update this table

`UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int`

This query brings an array of values and works.

```
select catalog_product_entity.sku,catalog_product_relation.parent_id,catalog_product_flat_1.special_price
from catalog_product_entity 
left join catalog_product_relation on (catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.parent_id)  
left join catalog_product_flat_1 on (catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.child_id)
where catalog_product_entity.type_id = "configurable"
and catalog_product_flat_1.special_price > 1
GROUP BY catalog_product_relation.parent_id;
```

This is what I want to set based on the above query

```
SET catalog_product_entity_int.value = 1
where catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id ='579' 
and catalog_product_relation.parent_id = catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id
```

I'm not sure if I need to get the select query into a temp table first and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Theeasiest way is to join both table

i added aliases for he table to make it more readable

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int t1,(select catalog_product_entity.sku,catalog_product_relation.parent_id,catalog_product_flat_1.special_price
from catalog_product_entity 
left join catalog_product_relation on (catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.parent_id)  
left join catalog_product_flat_1 on (catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.child_id)
where catalog_product_entity.type_id = "configurable"
and catalog_product_flat_1.special_price > 1
GROUP BY catalog_product_relation.parent_id) t2
SET t1.value = 1
where t1.attribute_id ='579' 
and t2.parent_id = t1.entity_id
```

`catalog_product_entity.sku` and `catalog_product_flat_1.special_price` aren't used in the update and so you should check if they are needed

Try the select query

```
SELECT t1.value, t1.entity_id
FROM 
 catalog_product_entity_int t1 INNER JOIN (select catalog_product_entity.sku,catalog_product_relation.parent_id,catalog_product_flat_1.special_price
from catalog_product_entity 
left join catalog_product_relation on (catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.parent_id)  
left join catalog_product_flat_1 on (catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.child_id)
where catalog_product_entity.type_id = "configurable"
and catalog_product_flat_1.special_price > 1
GROUP BY catalog_product_relation.parent_id) t2
ON  t2.parent_id = t1.entity_id
where t1.attribute_id ='579'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first query gets 2,500 rows of data. how does the set part know that it is working with a resulting set of rows and how does it update them one row at a time?
I just tested and it fails on line 1,7 and 8 Thanks anyway.

Comment: please provide the exact error message and add it to the question for better format

Comment: not as inage as text pkease

Comment: 1 row affected. (Query took 0.2065 seconds.)
 it should update about 2,500 rows.

Comment: @MartinLeeney i added a select query that rows which rows are effected. the is you use to make a query tht fits your need and then change the ppdaze

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. In the end this is what i did to make it work.
First create a temp table to store the values of the query

```
CREATE TABLE on_sale_updating AS  
select catalog_product_entity.sku,catalog_product_relation.parent_id,catalog_product_flat_1.special_price 
from catalog_product_entity 
left join catalog_product_relation on (catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.parent_id)  
left join catalog_product_flat_1 on (catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = catalog_product_relation.child_id)
where catalog_product_entity.type_id = "configurable"
and catalog_product_flat_1.special_price > 1
and catalog_product_flat_1.special_to_date IS NULL OR catalog_product_flat_1.special_to_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY catalog_product_relation.parent_id;
```

Then run an update query against the temp table

```
update catalog_product_entity_int
inner join on_sale_updating ON catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id = on_sale_updating.parent_id
SET catalog_product_entity_int.value = 1
where catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id ='579'
```

Once run for the first time add

```
DROP TABLE on_sale_updating;
```

to the first part.